# Pass a value from javascript to bootstrap modal view

Tags: javascript, html, variables, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I've got a google table that listens to a select event and then shows a modal bootstrap. Is it possible to have my modal text display data from the selected row?

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', function () {
            var row = table.getSelection()[0].row;
            alert(data.getValue(row, 0))
            $("#myModal").modal();
});
```

The alert shows the string I want in my modal window as well.
With the following modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body edit-content">
                            <p id='inputId'>Display text here.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var modalcontent = data.getValue(row, 0);
$("#inputId").html(modalcontent);
```

right before `$("#myModal").modal();`

[Here you can find the doc for this method.](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. Was trying way to complicated solutions obviously!

Comment: Hehehe. Be my guest ;)